# Need of Receipt Validation with Hosted Content

Tags: ios, validation, ios6, storekit, receipt

Simply put, if I am only supporting iOS 6, is there a need for receipt validation from a separate server if the product **must** download hosted content from Apple's servers?

Answer (score 0):

This is a question of how much **risk** you are willing to take.

While receipt validation is optional, you are vulnerable to potential exploits and bugs that may be found in later iOS versions (apart from the one known and stated by Apple for iOS 5.1 and earlier) if you choose not to implement it.

Personally I'd suggest you implement receipt validation, as you can reuse the server side for all your apps with little to no hassle.

If your question is related to cost of a server you'd otherwise not need, you have to weight that versus the potential for another exploit or bug (which may be fairly minimal). As stated before, at the end, it all boils down to the risk you are willing to take.